# create profile pages with different data on the fly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL table called artists, the index page includes a list of all artists's name, I want the user to click the artist's name to go into a profile page which includes the artist's data, so the php would create the profile page based on the profile template and the artist's id instead of creating hundreds of pages for every artist, how can I do that

edit:
the fetch php page code

```
<?php
include("config.php"); //include config file
//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

//throw HTTP error if page number is not valid
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
    exit();
}

//get current starting point of records
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

//fetch records using page position and item per page.
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, location, score, img FROM artists ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT ?, ?");

//bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
//for more info https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage
$results->bind_param("ss", $position, $item_per_page);
$results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
$results->bind_result($name, $location, $score, $img); //bind variables to prepared statement

//output results from database

while($results->fetch()){ //fetch values
    echo "<a href=<div class=\"feed_item\">";
    echo "<img src=\"img/" . $img . ".jpg\"class=\"feed_img\">";
    echo "<h2 class=\"feed_title\">" . $name . "</h2>";
    echo "<h4 class=\"feed_subtitle\">" . $location . "</h4>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

my table has ID column in it, I'm feeling lost and don't know what to search for in google/here.

Answer (score 1):

If you give some code to show how you are currently querying your database to get a list of all artists then we would be able to give you more assistance.

In general terms, what you need to do is perform a query and then loop through each result. Within the loop you need to set a link that points to `artist.php?id=XX` where XX is the id of the specific artist in the loop.

You can then create a new script called `artist.php` that has a query to pick up the ID that was sent in the GET request.

e.g.

```
select * from artists where id='$id'
```

You can then perform this query, fetch the results for this one artist and then display the details on screen.

This is high level but hopefully gives you an idea of the approach you need to take.

Comment: updated with my code, so I create one profile page as a template, load its content from the table, then?